# CSS alignment on my webpage between two elements

Tags: html, css, iframe, alignment, displaytag

I have two elements on my page which I wish to align side by side, what would be the best way of going about this, and can somebody explain the best way to go about coding it when you want to align elements together.

In this example I want the video to take up most of the room say 3/4 and the chart to be in the remaining 1/4. (Bootstrap is loaded on this page)

Any suggestions? 
This is what it currently looks like:

http://i1057.photobucket.com/albums/t390/Alexwileyy/element_zps066ecdd2.png
(I have outlined the video in a color so I can see the perimeters)

**This is my HTML code for the two elements:**

```
<!--Video Section-->
<div class="video">
<div class="container">
    <div class="video-element">
        <iframe width="460" height="215" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/PdABTJhRTLY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--End Of Video Section-->

<!--Start of chart-->
<div class="container">
<div class="chart">
<div class="chart-cont">
<h1 id="chart-header">Charts</h1>
</div>
<div class="chart-cont">
    <h1>1</h1>
    <img src="http://www.spotlightreport.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/gran-tourismo-6-banner-3.jpg">
    <a href="#" class="view-review">View Review</a></td>
</div>
<div class="chart-cont">
    <h1>2</h1>
    <img src="http://savegameonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CoD-Ghosts-banner.png">
    <a href="#" class="view-review">View Review</a></td>
</div>
<div class="chart-cont">
    <h1>3</h1>
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1tSu4iq">
    <a href="#" class="view-review">View Review</a></td>
</div>
<div class="chart-cont">
    <h1>4</h1>
    <img src="http://www.spotlightreport.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/gran-tourismo-6-banner-3.jpg">
    <a href="#" class="view-review">View Review</a></td>
</div>
<div class="chart-cont">
<a href="#"><h4>View More..</h4></a>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<!--End of chart-->
```

**This is my CSS code for my two elements:**

```
.chart {
background-color:white;
width:400px;

margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:-35px;
}
.chart-cont * {
display:inline;
}
.chart-cont {
padding:10px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(26,26,26,0.75);
text-align:center;
}
.chart-cont img {
width:180;
height:60px;
}
.chart-cont h1 {
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Any answers **greatly** appreciated.

Comment: did it fix your problem?

Comment: Yes it did, I have understood this a lot better now thank you! One more question, you know the video element, if I wanted to have text aligned on the left, how would I do it? I have tried text align, but when setting it to left it makes the text disapear somewhere? Links below for code and pictures:

http://bit.ly/1mteDn6

`.video {
    width:750px;
    height:420px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.video-element {
    background-color:blue;
    width:460px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.video p {
    text-align:center;
}`

Comment: HTML
`<div class="LeftContent">
<div class="video">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="video-element">
            <iframe width="460" height="215" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/PdABTJhRTLY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <p>Watch dog has recently come onto the market</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: Try to make use of JSFiddle, like I did. - By default text is aligned to the left. The next problem is that the video is in a frame, so the text is behind the video. Make sure to have another DIV below the video and put the text in there, this will probably fix your problem.

Comment: I have tried this but still no luck, I have outlined the text in red and it is behaving weird. IF I set the width of the text to 100% I would expect it to fill the yellow box as it is inside that div? But it does not, it spans the width of both elements if set to 100%.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/aj5xt/

Comment: you want "Watch dog has recently come onto the market" to be aligned to the left? Just remove text-align:right; in the .VideoText. Then I've tried in your fiddle link, when you put the width to 100% it fills from left to right like it should. It doesn't fill below your line because you don't have a height property, put in a height property or add new lines: http://fiddle.jshell.net/aj5xt/1/

Comment: Like this: http://bit.ly/WvcRgr
I haven't got enough rep, could you possibly start a chat? Easier that way?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/aj5xt/2/ Maybe add some margin to the frame.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57629/discussion-between-ragecompex-and-alex-wiley).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you want to work with 3/4 of the screen, start using a percentage as width.

First create a content Div, then a LeftContent and a RightContent div.

Like this:

```
<div class="Content">
    <div class="LeftContent">

    </div>

    <div class="RightContent">

    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.Content{
 width:100%;
margin:10px;
padding:10px;    

}
.LeftContent{
width:60%;
margin:10px;
float:left;
}

.RightContent{
width:30%;
margin:10px;
float:right;
}
```

Now you can place the video left, and the other images right, adjust how you want to with padding, margin and width percentage, test with making your window smaller (how it looks like on smaller screens).
Notice to make use of float left and float right.
Here is JSFiddle link: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7pp7q/1/